# Позиционирование вертикальное

Tags: css, css3, позиционирование

Подскажите как поменять местами блоки в разных родителях.

Пробовал и позитион абсолют и отрицательный марджин и флоут не выходит,

Спасибо!

Поменять нужно div `class="projects__galery"` и div `class="projects__slide-show"`

```html
<div class="projects__content">
  <div class="projects__body">
    <h2 class="projects__title">
      Completed <br>projects
    </h2>
    <p class="projects__txt">
      Only a small part of the work performed by our company is presented on the site. For 14 years on in the construction
      <br>market we have made happy more than 1000 families
    </p>
    <div class="projects__slide-show">
      <div class="projects__slide">
        <h3 class="projects__slide-title">
          City:
        </h3>
        <span class="projects__slide-txt city">
                                        Rostov-on-Don<br>LCD admiral
                                    </span>
      </div>
      <div class="projects__slide">
        <h3 class="projects__slide-title">
          apartment area:
        </h3>
        <span class="projects__slide-txt area">
                                        81 m2
                                    </span>
      </div>
      <div class="projects__slide">
        <h3 class="projects__slide-title">
          Repair time:
        </h3>
        <span class="projects__slide-txt time">
                                        3.5 months
                                    </span>
      </div>
      <div class="projects__slide">
        <h3 class="projects__slide-title">
          Repair Cost:
        </h3>
        <span class="projects__slide-txt cost">Upon request</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="projects__nav">
      <div class="projects__arrow-left">
        <img src="/img/svg/arrow-left.svg" alt="arrow-left">
      </div>
      <div class="projects__dot">
        <span class="projects__dot-1" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="projects__dot-2" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="projects__dot-3" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="projects__arrow-right">
        <img src="/img/svg/arrow-right.svg" alt="arrow-right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="projects__new-nav">
    <div class="projects__newarrow-left">
      <img src="/img/svg/arrow-open-left.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="projects__newarrow-right">
      <img src="/img/svg/arrow-open-rigft.svg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="projects__galery">
    <ul class="projects__list">
      <li class="projects__item-1"><a class="projects__link-1 activ">Rostov-on-Don, Admiral</a></li>
      <li class="projects__item-2"><a class="projects__link-2">Sochi Thieves</a></li>
      <li class="projects__item-3"><a class="projects__link-3">Rostov-on-Don Patriotic</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Исходя из моих познаний в css никак. Легче HTML поправить

Comment: Можно повесить `display: flex` на `projects__content`, все блоки вынести на один уровень и проставить `order`. Пример: https://codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/bGxGZBx Но подозреваю что это не то решение, которое применимо конкретно в вашем случае.

Comment: да вы абсолютно правы это не тот случай благодарю за помощь если кому то интересно могу поделиться "костылями"